# Can I used android:digits to only allow a single space?

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my EditText I need to restrict all characters except letters, numbers and **single** space. I tried to add to XML:

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 "
```

I still able to enter more than one space. How can I change this and allow to user enter no more than 1 space?

Comment: You could validate user input after submit and return an error message if there's more than one space

Answer (score 0):

You have to check it programmatically. But keep the XML stuff that you have. That's still good. Just check the number of spaces. Try this:

```
    String str = myEditText.toString();
    int first = str.indexOf(" ");
    boolean noneOrOneSpace = (first != -1) ? str.indexOf(" ", first + 1) : true;
```

Then you need apply it to use it in the textChangedListener for the editText. When a change occurs then remove and you notice a second space then remove the last character in the EditText

Answer (score 0):

digits will not work in this case.

You can try using TextWatcher and then by replacing all the multiple spaces entered by the user to a single space.

Eg:

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                yourEditText.removeTextChangeListener(this);

                // Uses append() method on edit-text instead of setText()
                // in an order to prevent soft keyboard reset.
                String tempStr = s.toString().substring(0, s.length());
                yourEditText.getText().clear();

                // This line replaces all the multiple spaces with single space.
                tempStr = tempStr.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");

                yourEditText.append(tempStr);
                yourEditText.setSelection(tempStr.length());

                yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet which works perfectly fine. Call this in after text changed it not going into an infinite loop while set text in TextWatcher

```
public void handleSpaceValidation(EditText editText, Editable editable) {
    String s = editText.getText().toString();
    int count = 0;
    loop:
    for (int i = 0; i < editable.length(); i++) {
        if (editable.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            count++;
            if (count > 1) {
                String after = s.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
                editText.setText(after);
                editText.setSelection(after.length());
                break loop;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got a clean solution:

```
 inputText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                int whiteSpaceCount = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < s.toString().length(); i++) {
                    if (Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
                        whiteSpaceCount++;
                    }
                    if (whiteSpaceCount > 1 && !Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))) {
                        s.replace(i, i + 1, "");
                    }else if (!Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && !Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
                        s.replace(i, i + 1, "");
                    }
                }
            }

        });
```

I hope it helps, and don't forget to **trim the inputText before displaying it in the end**, so that if the user enters the whiteSpace at the start or end, we can trim it.

Answer (score -1):

Digits doesn't have that type of power.  You'll have to make a custom filter for your EditText.

Comment: can you provide some example?

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved my problem, I have to allow only one space at typing time.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                Log.e("BeforeText", String.valueOf(s));
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                Log.e("OnText", String.valueOf(s));



//
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Log.e("AfterText", String.valueOf(s));
                if(editText.getText().toString().length()>1)
                {
                    if(editText.getText().toString()
                            .charAt(editText.getText().toString().length()-1)
                            ==editText.getText().toString()
                            .charAt(editText.getText().toString().length()-2))
                    {
                        String value=editText.getText().toString().substring(0,
                                editText.getText().toString().length()-1);
                        editText.setText(value);
                        editText.setSelection(value.length());
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```